# Increasing axis ranges

Tags: r, plot

I have a plot that I have added a second line to using `lines()` function but the added line does not fit within the default axis span so I want to increase the range of both axis so the whole of the new line fits. The code for the graph is the following:

```
plot(spa8, ci.type="line", col="black", lwd=2, ci.lty=2, ci.col="black",
 ylab = "Species Richness", yaxp = c(0,60,6), xaxp = c(0,200,10),
 cex.axis = 0.75, frame.plot=FALSE, xvar = "individuals") +
 lines(spa7, ci.type="line", col="grey", lwd=2, ci.lty=2, ci.col="grey",
 xvar = "individuals")+
 box(bty="L")
```

I have tried using `usr()` and `xaxp()`but with no luck, I have also tried to set my own axis using the `axis()` function but that hasn't worked either. I'm sure I must be doing something wrong here as it seems like something that should be simple to do!

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could play around with the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments within the `plot` function. For example, try running the code below (line by line) and look at the difference.

```
##  Default.
plot(1:10)

##  Set x-axis to be between -10 and 10.
plot(1:10, xlim = c(-10, 10))

##  Set x-axis to be between -10 and 10, and y-axis to be between -5 and 5.
plot(1:10, xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-5, 5))
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Adjusting the `xlim` and `ylim` results in me getting an error that x and y lengths differ. Edit: wait now I've restarted RStudio its worked this time.